# How to find two consecutive repeating characters in RGB using Regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to find all RGB numbers, that have 2x3 consecutive numbers. By that, I mean this sort of numbers:

```
\#00FF11
\#66AA44
\#FF0000
```

I have tried writing this:

```
\b#(([0-9a-zA-Z])\1){3}\b
```

but that doesn't work.

Where is the problem? I would probably say, that the problem is somewhere around the `\1`, because it's the only part I am not so sure about.

Comment: Replace `\1` with `\2` and `\b` with `\B` at the start. Try `@"\B#(([0-9a-fA-F])\2){3}\b"` or `@"\B#(?:([0-9a-fA-F])\1){3}\b"`

Comment: just  add `?:` in the outer capturing group. check this you https://regex101.com/r/JYIBuY/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\1` pattern is a backreference to the Capturing group 1, i.e. `(([0-9a-zA-Z])\1)`. You actually want to refer to Capturing group 2 and thus need `\2` instead of `\1`.

Note that `\b#` will only match `#` that is preceded with a word char (letter, digit or `_`). You need to use a non-word boundary at the start, `\B`.

To match hex chars, `[A-Fa-f]` is preferable rather than `[A-Za-z]`.

Use

```
@"\B#(?:([0-9a-fA-F])\1){3}\b"
```

Using the verbatim string literal, you do not need to double escape backslashes here.

Comment: Nice, just what I needed.. Thanks!!