# How can I easily find grey color with Regex?

Tags: c#, regex

Okay, so I've got 3 tasks. (Each of them is a task on it's own)

1. I have to find gray colors with 6 numbers.
   -> #555555.
2. I have to find gray colors with only 3 number.
   -> #555
3. I have to find only save gray colors, so only 0, 3, 6, 9, c, f
   -> #cccccc

First of all, is there a way, to compare just a value from groups? I wanted to use "\1" (with other numbers as well), but that didn't work. Is it right, that the number in "\1" refers to the Group1?
Second of all, is there an easier way, to do these tasks?

Many thanks for the help!

Comment: If you want to use regexes back references are the correct choice. With the answers to your [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54203601/how-to-find-two-consecutive-repeating-characters-in-rgb-using-regex) question you should be able to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These regexes are quite simple, the invidual regeces could be:

1. `\B#([0-9a-fA-F]{2})\1\1\b`
2. `\B#([0-9a-fA-F])\1\1\b`
3. `\B#([0369cf]{2})\1\1\b`

But you can merge 1. und 2 to one regex:

```
\B#([0-9a-fA-F]{1,2})\1\1\b
```

If you also want to merge the third you just have to adjust the valid character list.

```
\B#([0369cf]{1,2})\1\1\b
```

---

I'm not sure what you meant with

> is there a way, to compare just a value from groups?

But if your question was how to match the exact same characters again, you are right to use backreferences (`\1`, ...). This will match the capturing group with that number again. To use a backreference you have to create a group `(someexp)`.